# Digit sum of central binomial coefficients

Tags: fastest-code, number-theory

The task is simply to see how much faster you can calculate n choose n/2 (for even n) than the builtin function in python.  Of course for large n this is a rather large number so rather than output the whole number you should output the sum of the digits. For example, for `n = 100000`, the answer is `135702`. For `n=1000000` it is `1354815`.

Here is the python code:

```
from scipy.misc import comb
def sum_digits(n):
   r = 0
   while n:
       r, n = r + n % 10, n / 10
   return r
sum_digits(comb(n,n/2,exact=True))
```

Your score is `(highest n on your machine using your code)/(highest n on your machine using my code)`.  Your code must terminate in 60 seconds or less.

Your program must give the correct output for all even n: 2 <= n <= (your highest n)

You can't use any builtin code or libraries which calculate binomial coefficients or values which can quickly be transformed into binomial coefficients.

You can use any language of your choice.

---

**Leading answer**   The current leading answer with an amazing 680.09 is by justhalf.

Comment: Are we supposed to submit solutions in python or in a language of choice?

Comment: It's possible to write a routine that does this on a modern computer and takes `n` well into the millions, while I doubt the Python function would handle anything greater than `n = 1e5` without choking.

Comment: @Alessandro You can use any language of your choice. The only restriction was that you can't use builtin functions to compute the coefficients.

Comment: @COTO That sounds very interesting. I look forward to seeing it!

Comment: It was just an observation, @Lembik. I'm unfortunately splitting my time between work and one of the existing challenges at this point. I'll upvote the question to get it a bit of exposure, however. ;)

Comment: What if my highest n is n=1? (What I want to say is that someone might profit from having a much lower/higher n than someone else in regard of the time complexity of each algorithm) I'd suggest that the algorithm has to work up to a certain (fixed) n and that the timing is calculate according to that.

Comment: I want to point of [Lucas' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas'_theorem) and this [generalization to higher powers](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/BinCoeff.pdf) , though unfortunately 10 is not prime.

Comment: @COTO Well into the millions is an understatement. On my old Core Quad 6600 I can get a result for n = 100,000,000 in 32 seconds in C with mpz_bin_uiui(). I actually takes twice as long to stream the digits to the terminal...

Comment: @Comintern Part of the challenge is not being able to use a built-in function.

Comment: @qwr - That's why I didn't post it as an answer. ;-)   Mainly wanted to give a frame of reference for performance.

Comment: Are factorial functions allowed? I assumed not since they could be "quickly transformed into binomial coefficients" (the whole thing is just one factorial divided by another factorial squared), but since an answer is using one now, clarity would be nice.

Comment: @Geobits You are right that using a built in factorial function is cheating.

Comment: @Comintern: I have successfully replicated that point of reference with 287mil in 1 min, or 169mil in 35 secs! :)

Comment: Just realized that the 287mil in 1 min **includes** the time to convert the result into string. The calculation itself takes only a third of the time (like Comintern noticed in his/her comment): around 18s.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## C++ (GMP) - (287,000,000 / 422,000) = 680.09

Shamelessly combine Kummer's Theorem by xnor and GMP by qwr.
<s>Still not even close to the Go solution, not sure why.</s>

**Edit:** Thanks Keith Randall for the reminder that multiplication is faster if the number is similar in size. I implemented multi-level multiplication, similar to memory coalescing concept on memory management. And the result is impressive. What used to take 51s, now takes only 0.5s (i.e., 100-fold improvement!!)

```
OLD CODE (n=14,000,000)
Done sieving in 0.343s
Done calculating binom in 51.929s
Done summing in 0.901s
14000000: 18954729

real    0m53.194s
user    0m53.116s
sys 0m0.060s

NEW CODE (n=14,000,000)
Done sieving in 0.343s
Done calculating binom in 0.552s
Done summing in 0.902s
14000000: 18954729

real    0m1.804s
user    0m1.776s
sys 0m0.023s
```

The run for `n=287,000,000`

```
Done sieving in 4.211s
Done calculating binom in 17.934s
Done summing in 37.677s
287000000: 388788354

real    0m59.928s
user    0m58.759s
sys 0m1.116s
```

The code. Compile with `-lgmp -lgmpxx -O3`

```cpp
#include <gmpxx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdio>

const int MAX=287000000;
const int PRIME_COUNT=15700000;

int primes[PRIME_COUNT], factors[PRIME_COUNT], count;
bool sieve[MAX];
int max_idx=0;

void run_sieve(){
    sieve[2] = true;
    primes[0] = 2;
    count = 1;
    for(int i=3; i<MAX; i+=2){
        sieve[i] = true;
    }
    for(int i=3; i<17000; i+=2){
        if(!sieve[i]) continue;
        for(int j = i*i; j<MAX; j+=i){
            sieve[j] = false;
        }
    }
    for(int i=3; i<MAX; i+=2){
        if(sieve[i]) primes[count++] = i;
    }
}

mpz_class sum_digits(mpz_class n){
    clock_t t = clock();
    char* str = mpz_get_str(NULL, 10, n.get_mpz_t());
    int result = 0;
    for(int i=0;str[i]>0;i++){
        result+=str[i]-48;
    }
    printf("Done summing in %.3fs\n", ((float)(clock()-t))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return result;
}

mpz_class nc2_fast(const mpz_class &x){
    clock_t t = clock();
    int prime;
    const unsigned int n = mpz_get_ui(x.get_mpz_t());
    const unsigned int n2 = n/2;
    unsigned int m;
    unsigned int digit;
    unsigned int carry=0;
    unsigned int carries=0;
    mpz_class result = 1;
    mpz_class prime_prods = 1;
    mpz_class tmp;
    mpz_class tmp_prods[32], tmp_prime_prods[32];
    for(int i=0; i<32; i++){
        tmp_prods[i] = (mpz_class)NULL;
        tmp_prime_prods[i] = (mpz_class)NULL;
    }
    for(int i=0; i< count; i++){
        prime = primes[i];
        carry=0;
        carries=0;
        if(prime > n) break;
        if(prime > n2){
            tmp = prime;
            for(int j=0; j<32; j++){
                if(tmp_prime_prods[j] == NULL){
                    tmp_prime_prods[j] = tmp;
                    break;
                } else {
                    mpz_mul(tmp.get_mpz_t(), tmp.get_mpz_t(), tmp_prime_prods[j].get_mpz_t());
                    tmp_prime_prods[j] = (mpz_class)NULL;
                }
            }
            continue;
        }
        m=n2;
        while(m>0){
            digit = m%prime;
            carry = (2*digit + carry >= prime) ? 1 : 0;
            carries += carry;
            m/=prime;
        }
        if(carries>0){
            tmp = 0;
            mpz_ui_pow_ui(tmp.get_mpz_t(), prime, carries);
            for(int j=0; j<32; j++){
                if(tmp_prods[j] == NULL){
                    tmp_prods[j] = tmp;
                    break;
                } else {
                    mpz_mul(tmp.get_mpz_t(), tmp.get_mpz_t(), tmp_prods[j].get_mpz_t());
                    tmp_prods[j] = (mpz_class)NULL;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    result = 1;
    prime_prods = 1;
    for(int j=0; j<32; j++){
        if(tmp_prods[j] != NULL){
            mpz_mul(result.get_mpz_t(), result.get_mpz_t(), tmp_prods[j].get_mpz_t());
        }
        if(tmp_prime_prods[j] != NULL){
            mpz_mul(prime_prods.get_mpz_t(), prime_prods.get_mpz_t(), tmp_prime_prods[j].get_mpz_t());
        }
    }
    mpz_mul(result.get_mpz_t(), result.get_mpz_t(), prime_prods.get_mpz_t());
    printf("Done calculating binom in %.3fs\n", ((float)(clock()-t))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    const mpz_class n = atoi(argv[1]);
    clock_t t = clock();
    run_sieve();
    printf("Done sieving in %.3fs\n", ((float)(clock()-t))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    std::cout << n << ": " << sum_digits(nc2_fast(n)) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Multiplies are more efficient if both operands are about the same size.  You are always multiplying big number times little number.  If you repeatedly combine the small numbers in pairs it might be faster  (but take more memory).

Comment: Wow, that makes a whole lot of difference. It's exponentially faster. I can reach 169mil now in 35 secs.

Comment: Wow indeed!  What is the breakdown in time for the different parts of your code?

Comment: I've already put that up in my answer. 4s in generating primes up to `n`, 18s calculating the central binomial coefficient, and the rest 37s in converting the result into string and summing the digit.

Comment: I feel this answer should be contributed to any open source libraries that compute binomial coefficients. I can't believe anyone else has code this fast!

Comment: Thanks for the compliment, and thank you to all that make this answer possible. The caveat for this is memory requirement. It requires you to compute list of prime numbers beforehand. And I think based on Comintern's comment, there should already be library than can compute the coefficient efficiently.

Comment: What was the memory usage for 287,000,000 ? You may be right that there exists really efficient code for this already but I don't think it's in scipy, for example. Normally there are licensing reasons why the fastest code is stuck in one project. Also, I would love to see a comparison between your code and the code that Comintern pointed to.

Comment: I didn't measure, not sure how to check exact memory usage in C++, I usually work in Python. But for storing the primes, we can calculate. Assuming 4 bytes per int, with 15.7M prime numbers we need around 60MB. That doesn't include the memory for storing the result. Perhaps another 100MB.

Comment: That's interesting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process gives lots of ways of measuring memory usage as well but your method looks fine.

Comment: Valgrind is a decent memory profiler - take a look into the [Massif](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html#ms-manual.running-massif) tool.

Comment: It seems currently the biggest time consumption you have is summing the digits. You can further optimize that by precalculating the sum of digits for all the numbers up to 1 million (or bigger power of ten, which will fit in memory) and then splitting the number in chunks with known sum.

Comment: Precalculating should also be counted towards the total score, so in this case it wouldn't matter much, even I think it could be worse due to unnecessary digit sum. I've tried to find faster one, but I haven't been able to find anything faster. Division, which should have already be by GMP internally, seems to be the fastest so far.

Comment: You can sum digits mathematically with modulo 10, it should be faster

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input, but like I said, the modulo (which should include division) should have already been done by GMP internally =)

Answer (score 7):

### Go, 33.96 = (16300000 / 480000)

```
package main

import "math/big"

const n = 16300000

var (
    sieve     [n + 1]bool
    remaining [n + 1]int
    count     [n + 1]int
)

func main() {
    println("finding primes")
    for p := 2; p <= n; p++ {
        if sieve[p] {
            continue
        }
        for i := p * p; i <= n; i += p {
            sieve[i] = true
        }
    }

    // count net number of times each prime appears in the result.
    println("counting factors")
    for i := 2; i <= n; i++ {
        remaining[i] = i
    }
    for p := 2; p <= n; p++ {
        if sieve[p] {
            continue
        }

        for i := p; i <= n; i += p {
            for remaining[i]%p == 0 { // may have multiple factors of p
                remaining[i] /= p

                // count positive for n!
                count[p]++
                // count negative twice for ((n/2)!)^2
                if i <= n/2 {
                    count[p] -= 2
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // ignore all the trailing zeros
    count[2] -= count[5]
    count[5] = 0

    println("listing factors")
    var m []uint64
    for i := 0; i <= n; i++ {
        for count[i] > 0 {
            m = append(m, uint64(i))
            count[i]--
        }
    }

    println("grouping factors")
    m = group(m)

    println("multiplying")
    x := mul(m)

    println("converting to base 10")
    d := 0
    for _, c := range x.String() {
        d += int(c - '0')
    }
    println("sum of digits:", d)
}

// Return product of elements in a.
func mul(a []uint64) *big.Int {
    if len(a) == 1 {
        x := big.NewInt(0)
        x.SetUint64(a[0])
        return x
    }
    m := len(a) / 2
    x := mul(a[:m])
    y := mul(a[m:])
    x.Mul(x, y) // fast because x and y are about the same length
    return x
}

// return a slice whose members have the same product
// as the input slice, but hopefully shorter.
func group(a []uint64) []uint64 {
    var g []uint64
    r := uint64(1)
    b := 1
    for _, x := range a {
        c := bits(x)
        if b+c <= 64 {
            r *= x
            b += c
        } else {
            g = append(g, r)
            r = x
            b = c
        }
    }
    g = append(g, r)
    return g
}

// bits returns the number of bits in the representation of x
func bits(x uint64) int {
    n := 0
    for x != 0 {
        n++
        x >>= 1
    }
    return n
}
```

Works by counting all the prime factors in the numerator and denominator and canceling matching factors.  Multiplies the leftovers to get the result.

More than 80% of the time is spent in converting to base 10.  There's got to be a better way to do that...

Comment: For problems which require printing large numbers in base 10 I usually find it helpful to write my own BigInteger class which stores numbers in base 1E9 ~ 2^30.

Comment: You are currently winning by a country mile.. as they say.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: I tried that, but it requires lots of %1e9 in the multiply code, which makes the multiply slow.

Answer (score 6):

### Python 3 (8.8 = 2.2 million / 0.25 million)

This is in Python, which isn't known for speed, so you can probably do better porting this to another language.

Primes generator taken from this [StackOverflow contest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035188).

```python
import numpy
import time

def primesfrom2to(n):
    """ Input n>=6, Returns a array of primes, 2 <= p < n """
    sieve = numpy.ones(n//3 + (n%6==2), dtype=numpy.bool)
    for i in range(1,int(n**0.5)//3+1):
        if sieve[i]:
            k=3*i+1|1
            sieve[       k*k/3     ::2*k] = False
            sieve[k*(k-2*(i&1)+4)/3::2*k] = False
    return numpy.r_[2,3,((3*numpy.nonzero(sieve)[0][1:]+1)|1)]

t0 = time.clock()

N=220*10**4
n=N//2

print("N = %d" % N)
print()

print("Generating primes.")
primes = primesfrom2to(N)

t1 = time.clock()
print ("Time taken: %f" % (t1-t0))

print("Computing product.")
product = 1

for p in primes:
    p=int(p)
    carries = 0 
    carry = 0

    if p>n:
        product*=p
        continue

    m=n

    #Count carries of n+n in base p as per Kummer's Theorem
    while m:
        digit = m%p
        carry = (2*digit + carry >= p)
        carries += carry
        m//=p

    if carries >0:
        for _ in range(carries):
            product *= p

    #print(p,carries,product)

t2 = time.clock()
print ("Time taken: %f" % (t2-t1))

print("Converting number to string.")

# digit_sum = 0
# result=product

# while result:
    # digit_sum+=result%10
    # result//=10

digit_sum = 0
digit_string = str(product)

t3 = time.clock()
print ("Time taken: %f" % (t3-t2))

print("Summing digits.")
for d in str(digit_string):digit_sum+=int(d)

t4 = time.clock()
print ("Time taken: %f" % (t4-t3))
print ()

print ("Total time: %f" % (t4-t0))
print()
print("Sum of digits = %d" % digit_sum)
```

The main idea of the algorithm is to use [Kummer's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem) to get the prime-factorization of the binomial. For each prime, we learn the highest power of it that divides the answer, and multiply the running product by that power of the prime. In this way, we only need to multiply once for each prime in the prime-factorization of the answer.

**Output showing time breakdown:**

```
N = 2200000
Generating primes.
Time taken: 0.046408
Computing product.
Time taken: 17.931472
Converting number to string.
Time taken: 39.083390
Summing digits.
Time taken: 1.502393

Total time: 58.563664

Sum of digits = 2980107
```

Surprisingly, most of the time is spent converting the number to a string to sum its digits. Also surprisingly, converting to a string was much faster than getting digits from repeated `%10` and `//10`, even though the whole string must presumably be kept in memory.

Generating the primes takes negligible time (and hence I don't feel unfair copying existing code). Summing digits is fast. The actual multiplication takes one third of the time.

Given that digit summing seems to be the limiting factor, perhaps an algorithm to multiply numbers in decimal representation would save time in total by shortcutting the binary/decimal conversion.

Comment: This is very impressive and makes you wonder why cpython doesn't use your implementation!

Answer (score 3):

### Java (score 22500 / 365000 = 0.062)

I don't have Python on this machine, so if someone could score this I would be grateful. If not, it will have to wait.

The basis of this implementation is
$$\binom{2n}{n} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2$$

The bottleneck is the addition to compute the relevant section of Pascal's triangle (90% of running time), so using a better multiplication algorithm wouldn't really help.

Note that what the question calls `n` is what I call `2n`. The command-line argument is what the question calls `n`.

```java
public class CodeGolf37270 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java CodeGolf37270 <n>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        int two_n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        // \binom{2n}{n} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2
        // Two cases:
        //   n = 2m: \binom{4m}{2m} = \binom{2m}{m}^2 + 2\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \binom{2m}{k}^2
        //   n = 2m+1: \binom{4m+2}{2m+1} = 2\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{2m+1}{k}^2
        int n = two_n / 2;
        BigInt[] nCk = new BigInt[n/2 + 1];
        nCk[0] = new BigInt(1);
        for (int k = 1; k < nCk.length; k++) nCk[k] = nCk[0];
        for (int row = 2; row <= n; row++) {
            BigInt tmp = nCk[0];
            for (int col = 1; col < row && col < nCk.length; col++) {
                BigInt replacement = tmp.add(nCk[col]);
                tmp = nCk[col];
                nCk[col] = replacement;
            }
        }

        BigInt central = nCk[0]; // 1^2 = 1
        int lim = (n & 1) == 1 ? nCk.length : (nCk.length - 1);
        for (int k = 1; k < lim; k++) central = central.add(nCk[k].sq());
        central = central.add(central);
        if ((n & 1) == 0) central = central.add(nCk[nCk.length - 1].sq());

        System.out.println(central.digsum());
    }

    private static class BigInt {
        static final int B = 1000000000;
        private int[] val;

        public BigInt(int x) {
            val = new int[] { x };
        }

        private BigInt(int[] val) {
            this.val = val;
        }

        public BigInt add(BigInt that) {
            int[] left, right;
            if (val.length < that.val.length) {
                left = that.val;
                right = val;
            }
            else {
                left = val;
                right = that.val;
            }

            int[] sum = left.clone();
            int carry = 0, k = 0;
            for (; k < right.length; k++) {
                int a = sum[k] + right[k] + carry;
                sum[k] = a % B;
                carry = a / B;
            }
            while (carry > 0 && k < sum.length) {
                int a = sum[k] + carry;
                sum[k] = a % B;
                carry = a / B;
                k++;
            }
            if (carry > 0) {
                int[] wider = new int[sum.length + 1];
                System.arraycopy(sum, 0, wider, 0, sum.length);
                wider[sum.length] = carry;
                sum = wider;
            }

            return new BigInt(sum);
        }

        public BigInt sq() {
            int[] rv = new int[2 * val.length];
            // Naive multiplication
            for (int i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
                for (int j = i; j < val.length; j++) {
                    int k = i+j;
                    long c = val[i] * (long)val[j];
                    if (j > i) c <<= 1;
                    while (c > 0) {
                        c += rv[k];
                        rv[k] = (int)(c % B);
                        c /= B;
                        k++;
                    }
                }
            }

            int len = rv.length;
            while (len > 1 && rv[len - 1] == 0) len--;
            if (len < rv.length) {
                int[] rv2 = new int[len];
                System.arraycopy(rv, 0, rv2, 0, len);
                rv = rv2;
            }

            return new BigInt(rv);
        }

        public long digsum() {
            long rv = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
                int x = val[i];
                while (x > 0) {
                    rv += x % 10;
                    x /= 10;
                }
            }
            return rv;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get 29,500 for your program and 440,000 for the reference program, so that would be a score of 0.067. This is compiling with Java 1.7 (`javac CodeGolf37270.java`) and executing with Java 1.8 (`java CodeGolf37270 n`). I'm not sure if there are any optimizations options I'm unaware of. I can't try compiling with Java 1.8, because it doesn't get installed with my Java package...

Comment: Interesting approach. Why do you think calculating it iteratively could be faster than using the simple formula?

Comment: @justhalf, I didn't have an intuition for whether it would be faster or not, and I didn't try to do complexity calculations. I looked through lists of identities for central binomial coefficients to try to find formulae which would be simple to implement with a custom big integer class optimised for extracting base-10 digits. And having discovered that it's not very efficient, I may as well post it and save someone else from repeating the experiment. (FWIW I'm working on Toom multiplication, but I'm not sure when I'll have it tested and debugged).

Answer (score 2):

## GMP - 1500000 / 300000 = 5.0

Although this answer won't compete against sieves, sometimes short code can still get results.

```
#include <gmpxx.h>
#include <iostream>
    
mpz_class sum_digits(mpz_class n)
{
    char* str = mpz_get_str(NULL, 10, n.get_mpz_t());
    int result = 0;
    for(int i=0; str[i]>0; i++)
         
    result += str[i] - 48;

    return result;
}


mpz_class comb_2(const mpz_class &x)
{
    const unsigned int k = mpz_get_ui(x.get_mpz_t()) / 2;
    mpz_class result = k + 1;

    for(int i=2; i<=k; i++)
    {
        result *= k + i;
        mpz_divexact_ui(result.get_mpz_t(), result.get_mpz_t(), i);
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    const mpz_class n = 1500000;
    std::cout << sum_digits(comb_2(n)) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Java, custom big integer class: 32.9 (120000000 / 365000)

The main class is pretty straightforward:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class PPCG37270 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();

        int n = 12000000;
        if (args.length == 1) n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        boolean[] sieve = new boolean[n + 1];
        int[] remaining = new int[n + 1];
        int[] count = new int[n + 1];

        for (int p = 2; p <= n; p++) {
            if (sieve[p]) continue;
            long p2 = p * (long)p;
            if (p2 > n) continue;
            for (int i = (int)p2; i <= n; i += p) sieve[i] = true;
        }

        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) remaining[i] = i;
        for (int p = 2; p <= n; p++) {
            if (sieve[p]) continue;
            for (int i = p; i <= n; i += p) {
                while (remaining[i] % p == 0) {
                    remaining[i] /= p;
                    count[p]++;
                    if (i <= n/2) count[p] -= 2;
                }
            }
        }

        count[2] -= count[5];
        count[5] = 0;

        List<BigInt> partialProd = new ArrayList<BigInt>();
        long accum = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = count[i]; j > 0; j--) {
                long tmp = accum * i;
                if (tmp < 1000000000L) accum = tmp;
                else {
                    partialProd.add(new BigInt((int)accum));
                    accum = i;
                }
            }
        }
        partialProd.add(new BigInt((int)accum));
        System.out.println(prod(partialProd).digsum());
        System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000000 + "ms");
    }

    private static BigInt prod(List<BigInt> vals) {
        while (vals.size() > 1) {
            int n = vals.size();
            List<BigInt> next = new ArrayList<BigInt>();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 2) {
                if (i == n - 1) next.add(vals.get(i));
                else next.add(vals.get(i).mul(vals.get(i+1)));
            }
            vals = next;
        }
        return vals.get(0);
    }
}
```

It relies on a big integer class which is optimised for multiplication and `toString()`, both of which are significant bottlenecks in an implementation with `java.math.BigInteger`.

```java
/**
 * A big integer class which is optimised for conversion to decimal.
 * For use in simple applications where BigInteger.toString() is a bottleneck.
 */
public class BigInt {
    // The base of the representation.
    private static final int B = 1000000000;
    // The number of decimal digits per digit of the representation.
    private static final int LOG10_B = 9;

    public static final BigInt ZERO = new BigInt(0);
    public static final BigInt ONE = new BigInt(1);

    // We use sign-magnitude representation.
    private final boolean negative;

    // Least significant digit is at val[off]; most significant is at val[off + len - 1]
    // Unless len == 1 we guarantee that val[off + len - 1] is non-zero.
    private final int[] val;
    private final int off;
    private final int len;

    // Toom-style multiplication parameters from
    // Zuras, D. (1994). More on squaring and multiplying large integers. IEEE Transactions on Computers, 43(8), 899-908.
    private static final int[][][] Q = new int[][][]{
        {},
        {},
        {{1, -1}},
        {{4, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 4}},
        {{8, 4, 2, 1}, {-8, 4, -2, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, -2, 4, -8}, {1, 2, 4, 8}}
    };
    private static final int[][][] R = new int[][][]{
        {},
        {},
        {{1, -1, 1}},
        {{-21, 2, -12, 1, -6}, {7, -1, 10, -1, 7}, {-6, 1, -12, 2, -21}},
        {{-180, 6, 2, -80, 1, 3, -180}, {-510, 4, 4, 0, -1, -1, 120}, {1530, -27, -7, 680, -7, -27, 1530}, {120, -1, -1, 0, 4, 4, -510}, {-180, 3, 1, -80, 2, 6, -180}}
    };
    private static final int[][] S = new int[][]{
        {},
        {},
        {1, 1, 1},
        {1, 6, 2, 6, 1},
        {1, 180, 120, 360, 120, 180, 1}
    };

    /**
     * Constructs a big version of an integer value.
     * @param x The value to represent.
     */
    public BigInt(int x) {
        this(Integer.toString(x));
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a big version of a long value.
     * @param x The value to represent.
     */
    public BigInt(long x) {
        this(Long.toString(x));
    }

    /**
     * Parses a decimal representation of an integer.
     * @param str The value to represent.
     */
    public BigInt(String str) {
        this(str.charAt(0) == '-', split(str));
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a sign-magnitude representation taking the entire span of the array as the range of interest.
     * @param neg Is the value negative?
     * @param val The base-B digits, least significant first.
     */
    private BigInt(boolean neg, int[] val) {
        this(neg, val, 0, val.length);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a sign-magnitude representation taking a range of an array as the magnitude.
     * @param neg Is the value negative?
     * @param val The base-B digits, least significant at offset off, most significant at off + val - 1.
     * @param off The offset within the array.
     * @param len The number of base-B digits.
     */
    private BigInt(boolean neg, int[] val, int off, int len) {
        // Bounds checks
        if (val == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("val");
        if (off < 0 || off >= val.length) throw new IllegalArgumentException("off");
        if (len < 1 || off + len > val.length) throw new IllegalArgumentException("len");

        this.negative = neg;
        this.val = val;
        this.off = off;
        // Enforce the invariant that this.len is 1 or val[off + len - 1] is non-zero.
        while (len > 1 && val[off + len - 1] == 0) len--;
        this.len = len;

        // Sanity check
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (val[off + i] < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("val contains negative digits");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Splits a string into base-B digits.
     * @param str The string to parse.
     * @return An array which can be passed to the (boolean, int[]) constructor.
     */
    private static int[] split(String str) {
        if (str.charAt(0) == '-') str = str.substring(1);

        int[] arr = new int[(str.length() + LOG10_B - 1) / LOG10_B];
        int i, off;
        // Each element of arr represents LOG10_B characters except (probably) the last one.
        for (i = 0, off = str.length() - LOG10_B; off > 0; off -= LOG10_B) {
            arr[i++] = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(off, off + LOG10_B));
        }
        arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0, off + LOG10_B));
        return arr;
    }

    public boolean isZero() {
        return len == 1 && val[off] == 0;
    }

    public BigInt negate() {
        return new BigInt(!negative, val, off, len);
    }

    public BigInt add(BigInt that) {
        // If the signs differ, then since we use sign-magnitude representation we want to do a subtraction.
        boolean isSubtraction = negative ^ that.negative;

        BigInt left, right;
        if (len < that.len) {
            left = that;
            right = this;
        }
        else {
            left = this;
            right = that;

            // For addition I just care about the lengths of the arrays.
            // For subtraction I want the largest absolute value on the left.
            if (isSubtraction && len == that.len) {
                int cmp = compareAbsolute(that);
                if (cmp == 0) return ZERO; // Cheap special case
                if (cmp < 0) {
                    left = that;
                    right = this;
                }
            }
        }

        if (right.isZero()) return left;

        BigInt result;
        if (!isSubtraction) {
            int[] sum = new int[left.len + 1];
            // A copy here rather than using left.val in the main loops and copying remaining values
            // at the end gives a small performance boost, probably due to cache locality.
            System.arraycopy(left.val, left.off, sum, 0, left.len);

            int carry = 0, k = 0;
            for (; k < right.len; k++) {
                int a = sum[k] + right.val[right.off + k] + carry;
                sum[k] = a % B;
                carry = a / B;
            }
            for (; carry > 0 && k < left.len; k++) {
                int a = sum[k] + carry;
                sum[k] = a % B;
                carry = a / B;
            }
            sum[left.len] = carry;

            result = new BigInt(negative, sum);
        }
        else {
            int[] diff = new int[left.len];
            System.arraycopy(left.val, left.off, diff, 0, left.len);

            int carry = 0, k = 0;
            for (; k < right.len; k++) {
                int a = diff[k] - right.val[right.off + k] + carry;
                // Why did anyone ever think that rounding positive and negative divisions differently made sense?
                if (a < 0) {
                    diff[k] = a + B;
                    carry = -1;
                }
                else {
                    diff[k] = a % B;
                    carry = a / B;
                }
            }
            for (; carry != 0 && k < left.len; k++) {
                int a = diff[k] + carry;
                if (a < 0) {
                    diff[k] = a + B;
                    carry = -1;
                }
                else {
                    diff[k] = a % B;
                    carry = a / B;
                }
            }

            result = new BigInt(left.negative, diff, 0, k > left.len ? k : left.len);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private int compareAbsolute(BigInt that) {
        if (len > that.len) return 1;
        if (len < that.len) return -1;

        for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (val[off + i] > that.val[that.off + i]) return 1;
            if (val[off + i] < that.val[that.off + i]) return -1;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public BigInt mul(BigInt that) {
        if (isZero() || that.isZero()) return ZERO;

        if (len == 1) return that.mulSmall(negative ? -val[off] : val[off]);
        if (that.len == 1) return mulSmall(that.negative ? -that.val[that.off] : that.val[that.off]);

        int shorter = len < that.len ? len : that.len;
        BigInt result;
        // Cutoffs have been hand-tuned.
        if (shorter > 300) result = mulToom(3, that);
        else if (shorter > 28) result = mulToom(2, that);
        else result = mulNaive(that);

        return result;
    }

    BigInt mulSmall(int m) {
        if (m == 0) return ZERO;
        if (m == 1) return this;
        if (m == -1) return negate();

        // We want to do the magnitude calculation with a positive multiplicand.
        boolean neg = negative;
        if (m < 0) {
            neg = !neg;
            m = -m;
        }

        int[] pr = new int[len + 1];
        int carry = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            long t = val[off + i] * (long)m + carry;
            pr[i] = (int)(t % B);
            carry = (int)(t / B);
        }
        pr[len] = carry;
        return new BigInt(neg, pr);
    }

    // NB This truncates.
    BigInt divSmall(int d) {
        if (d == 0) throw new ArithmeticException();
        if (d == 1) return this;
        if (d == -1) return negate();

        // We want to do the magnitude calculation with a positive divisor.
        boolean neg = negative;
        if (d < 0) {
            neg = !neg;
            d = -d;
        }

        int[] div = new int[len];
        int rem = 0;
        for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            long t = val[off + i] + rem * (long)B;
            div[i] = (int)(t / d);
            rem = (int)(t % d);
        }

        return new BigInt(neg, div);
    }

    BigInt mulNaive(BigInt that) {
        int[] rv = new int[len + that.len];
        // Naive multiplication
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < that.len; j++) {
                int k = i + j;
                long c = val[off + i] * (long)that.val[that.off + j];
                while (c > 0) {
                    c += rv[k];
                    rv[k] = (int)(c % B);
                    c /= B;
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }

        return new BigInt(this.negative ^ that.negative, rv);
    }

    private BigInt mulToom(int k, BigInt that) {
        // We split each number into k parts of m base-B digits each.
        // m = ceil(longer / k)
        int m = ((len > that.len ? len : that.len) + k - 1) / k;

        // Perform the splitting and evaluation steps of Toom-Cook.
        BigInt[] f1 = this.toomFwd(k, m);
        BigInt[] f2 = that.toomFwd(k, m);

        // Pointwise multiplication.
        for (int i = 0; i < f1.length; i++) f1[i] = f1[i].mul(f2[i]);

        // Inverse (or interpolation) and recomposition.
        return toomBk(k, m, f1, negative ^ that.negative, val[off], that.val[that.off]);
    }

    // Splits a number into k parts of m base-B digits each and does the polynomial evaluation.
    private BigInt[] toomFwd(int k, int m) {
        // Split.
        BigInt[] a = new BigInt[k];
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            int o = i * m;
            if (o >= len) a[i] = ZERO;
            else {
                int l = m;
                if (o + l > len) l = len - o;
                // Ignore signs for now.
                a[i] = new BigInt(false, val, off + o, l);
            }
        }

        // Evaluate
        return transform(Q[k], a);
    }

    private BigInt toomBk(int k, int m, BigInt[] f, boolean neg, int lsd1, int lsd2) {
        // Inverse (or interpolation).
        BigInt[] b = transform(R[k], f);

        // Recomposition: add at suitable offsets, dividing by the normalisation factors
        BigInt prod = ZERO;
        int[] s = S[k];
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            int[] shifted = new int[i * m + b[i].len];
            System.arraycopy(b[i].val, b[i].off, shifted, i * m, b[i].len);
            prod = prod.add(new BigInt(neg ^ b[i].negative, shifted).divSmall(s[i]));
        }

        // Handle the remainders.
        // In the worst case the absolute value of the sum of the remainders is s.length, so pretty small.
        // It should be easy enough to work out whether to go up or down.
        int lsd = (int)((lsd1 * (long)lsd2) % B);
        int err = lsd - prod.val[prod.off];
        if (err > B / 2) err -= B / 2;
        if (err < -B / 2) err += B / 2;
        return prod.add(new BigInt(err));
    }

    /**
     * Multiplies a matrix of small integers and a vector of big ones.
     * The matrix has a implicit leading row [1 0 ... 0] and an implicit trailing row [0 ... 0 1].
     * @param m The matrix.
     * @param v The vector.
     * @return m v
     */
    private BigInt[] transform(int[][] m, BigInt[] v) {
        BigInt[] b = new BigInt[m.length + 2];
        b[0] = v[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            BigInt s = ZERO;
            for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) s = s.add(v[j].mulSmall(m[i][j]));
            b[i + 1] = s;
        }
        b[b.length - 1] = v[v.length - 1];

        return b;
    }

    /**
     * Sums the digits of this integer.
     * @return The sum of the digits of this integer.
     */
    public long digsum() {
        long rv = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            int x = val[off + i];
            while (x > 0) {
                rv += x % 10;
                x /= 10;
            }
        }
        return rv;
    }
}
```

The big bottleneck is naïve multiplication (60%), followed by the other multiplication (37%) and the sieving (3%). The `digsum()` call is insignificant.

Performance measured with OpenJDK 7 (64 bit).

Comment: Very nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## Java (2,020,000/491,000) = 4.11

**updated, previously 2.24**

Java `BigInteger` isn't the fastest number cruncher, but it's better than nothing.

The basic formula for this seems to be `n! / ((n/2)!^2)`, but that seems like a bunch of redundant multiplication.

You can get a significant speedup by eliminating all prime factors found in both the numerator and denominator. To do this, I first run a simple prime sieve. Then for each prime, I keep a count of what power it needs to be raised to. Increment each time I see a factor in the numerator, decrement for the denominator.

I handle twos separately (and first), since it's easy to count/eliminate them before factoring.

Once that's done, you have the minimum amount of multiplications necessary, which is good because BigInt multiply is *slow*.

```java
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CentBiCo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 2020000;
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        sieve(n);
        System.out.println(sumDigits(cbc(n)));
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()-time);
    }
    
    static boolean[] sieve;
    static List<Integer> primes;
    static void sieve(int n){
        primes = new ArrayList<Integer>((int)(Math.sqrt(n)));
        sieve = new boolean[n];
        sieve[2]=true;
        for(int i=3;i<sieve.length;i+=2)
            if(i%2==1)
                sieve[i] = true;
        for(int i=3;i<sieve.length;i+=2){
            if(!sieve[i])
                continue;
            for(int j=i*2;j<sieve.length;j+=i)
                sieve[j] = false;
        }
        for(int i=2;i<sieve.length;i++)
            if(sieve[i])
                primes.add(i);
    }
    
    static int[] factors;
    static void addFactors(int n, int flip){
        for(int k=0;primes.get(k)<=n;){
            int i = primes.get(k);
            if(n%i==0){
                factors[i] += flip;
                n /= i;
            } else {
                if(++k == primes.size())
                    break;
            }
        }
        factors[n]++;
    }
    
    static BigInteger cbc(int n){
        factors = new int[n+1];
        int x = n/2;
        for(int i=x%2<1?x+1:x+2;i<n;i+=2)
            addFactors(i,1);
        factors[2] = x;
        for(int i=1;i<=x/2;i++){
            int j=i;
            while(j%2<1 && factors[2] > 1){
                j=j/2;
                factors[2]--;
            }
            addFactors(j,-1);
            factors[2]--;
        }
        BigInteger cbc = BigInteger.ONE;
        for(int i=3;i<factors.length;i++){
            if(factors[i]>0)
                cbc = cbc.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i).pow(factors[i]));
        }
        return cbc.shiftLeft(factors[2]);
    }
    
    static long sumDigits(BigInteger in){
        long sum = 0;
        String str = in.toString();
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
            sum += str.charAt(i)-'0';
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Oh, and the output sum for n=2020000 is `2735298`, for verification purposes.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2 (PyPy), 1,134,000 / 486,000 = 2.32

```
#/!usr/bin/pypy
n=input(); a, b, c=1, 1, 2**((n+2)/4)
for i in range(n-1, n/2, -2): a*=i
for i in range(2, n/4+1): b*=i
print sum(map(int, str(a*c/b)))
```

#### Result: 1,537,506

Fun fact: The bottleneck of your code is adding the digits, not computing the binomial coefficient.

Comment: Why is python so slow at adding digits? Both you and xnor say it is. It made me curious, so I clocked mine. It came in at less than a second for the sum part (Java).

Comment: @Geobits Hmm, curious. Is Java also able to do binary-decimal conversions similarly fast? It does represent integers in binary, right?

Comment: That's a good question. For integer/Integer/long/Long I know it's binary. I'm not exactly sure what the internal representation of a BigInteger is. If it's decimal, that would definitely explain why it's slow at math but fast to convert to a string. May look that up tomorrow.

Comment: @Geobits, the internal representation of BigInteger is base 2.

Comment: I always assumed so, but it made me wonder. It looks like it's breaking it down into long-sized chunks and converting it that way, at least in OpenJDK.