# Calculate max depth of JSON data

Tags: fastest-code, json

### Challenge

Given some JSON data, calculate the maximum depth reached. (Both arrays and dictionaries increase the depth)

### Input/Output

The program is expected to read a JSON string from stdin and as soon as the program receives a \n start calculating the max depth, printing it to stdout and terminating the program when done.

If invalid JSON is provided, the output is undefined (the program can return anything).

### Test cases

`[]` -> 1

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` -> 1

`[ [ 123],   []]` -> 2

`[{"a": []}, ["abc"]]` -> 3

`{"a": 321}` -> 1

`{"a": []}` -> 2

`"hello"` -> 0

`["abc[]bca"]` -> 1

#### Evaluating machine/platform

Platform: aarch64 Linux (arch Linux arm, cpu: apple M1)

#### Results

| Contestant | Language | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AnttiP | C | 43 ± 11 ms |
| Philx0 | C | 67 ± 7 ms |
| 138 Aspen | rust | 112 ± 7 ms |
| Arnauld | node.js | 276 ± 18 ms |
| tsh | node.js | 370 ± 16 ms |
| noodle man | node.js | 567 ± 143 ms |

#### edit

Edit: changed challenge to not require outputting 0 in the case of invalid JSON

Comment: You've got the [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) tag, but you haven't specified where the solutions will be tested. I'd recommend testing them on your own computer. If you do that, you'll have to give the specifications of the device.

Comment: `hello` is not valid JSON. Is that on purpose, or did you mean `"hello"`?

Comment: @Arnauld `hello` is invalid on purpose, however `"hello"` should also return a depth of 0

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first challenge!

Comment: "If invalid JSON is provided, the output should be 0." makes this challenge feel like a [chameleon challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8214/92727) to me, because it seems like testing if a given string is valid JSON is harder than finding its maximum depth (which can be done by iterating over its characters and maintaining the depth).

Comment: @CommandMaster Thanks for pointing that out! I didn’t take that into account when creating the challenge. I'm going to change it now.

Comment: @TheThonnu for fastest code challenge, is it better to have a reference answer, and then have each answerer to compare the speed of that reference to their own? This way each answerer can test and optimize for speed by themselves instead of waiting for OP. Something like [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37270/digit-sum-of-central-binomial-coefficients)?

Comment: Suggested test cases: `["\\\",[],\\\""]` → 1, `["\\\\",[],"\\\\"]` → 2. Also, I assume you are generating large test cases to evaluate speed—in order to have an objective winning criterion, you need to share the details so that evaluation can be reproduced.

Comment: Swift isn't officially supported on Arch Linux (only Ubuntu, CentOS, and Amazon Linux), but I also see that you're using an Apple M1. Would I be able to submit an answer in Swift?

Comment: @Bbrk24 Unfortunately, I won’t be able to evaluate your answer in swift. However, for a rough estimate, you can run it on your machine and compare the time taken to AnttiP’s answer (also on your machine) and scale the time accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## C, based on Philx0's answer

I tried to remove a few branches. Instead of storing state in a variable I store it... in the state. Namely, there are two loops depending on if we are parsing a string or not. The rest of the comparisons should be branchless when compiled with -O3.

Edit: Slightly improved version. It's possible to also remove most checks for "\n" by keeping track of whether the current depth is positive, tough I'm not sure how much it would improve performance.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFSIZE 4096
#define unlikely(x) __builtin_expect((x),0)

int main(void) {
    int depth = 0;
    int maxdepth = 0;

    char buf[BUFSIZE];

    ssize_t cnt;
    ssize_t i;
    ssize_t skip = 0;

    int str = 0;

    while ((cnt = read(0,buf,BUFSIZE))) {
        i = skip;
        if (!str) {
            for (; i < cnt; i++) {
                if (buf[i] == '"') goto instring;
                if (unlikely(buf[i] == '\n')) goto print;
                if (depth > maxdepth) maxdepth = depth;
                depth+= buf[i] == '{' || buf[i] == '[';
                depth-= buf[i] == '}' || buf[i] == ']';
                outstring:;
            }
            str = 0;
        } else {
            for (; i < cnt; i++) {
                if (buf[i] == '"') goto outstring;
                if (unlikely(buf[i] == '\\')) i+=1;
                instring:;
            }
            str = 1;
        }
        skip = i - cnt;
    }

    print:

    printf("%d\n", maxdepth);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Result: 43 ± 11 ms

Answer (score 6):

## Rust

use `serde_json` crate. I don't know how fast it is.

upd 2023-06-19  \$\quad \$ In light of the comment of @lights0123, you can use `cargo build --release` instead of `cargo build`. It would likely be significantly faster in release mode.

#### `src/main.rs`

```rust
use std::io::{self, Read, BufRead};
use serde_json::Value;
use std::process;

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        let line = line?;
        let json_value: Value = serde_json::from_str(&line).unwrap_or(Value::Null);
        println!("{}", search(&json_value));
    }
    process::exit(0);
}

fn search(node: &Value) -> u32 {
    match node {
        Value::Object(map) => {
            let max_depth = map.values().map(|v| search(v)).max();
            match max_depth {
                Some(max) => 1 + max,
                None => 1,
            }
        },
        Value::Array(arr) => {
            let max_depth = arr.iter().map(|v| search(v)).max();
            match max_depth {
                Some(max) => 1 + max,
                None => 1,
            }
        },
        _ => 0,
    }
}
```

#### `Cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "rust_hello"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https:doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
serde_json = "1.0"
```

#### Build and running

```
# win10 environment

$ cargo build --release
$ target\release\rust_hello.exe
[{"a": []}, ["abc"]]
3
hello
0
{"a": []}
2
{"a": 321}
1
[ [ 123],   []]
2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1
[]
1
[[]
0
```

Comment: Result: 665 ± 13 ms. This is surprisingly slow for a compiled language, perhaps the JSON library has some overhead.

Comment: The challenge has been edited so that you don't need to handle invalid JSON. Hopefully that should speed up your answer :)

Comment: This answer demonstrates compiling without optimizations (`cargo build` without `--release`, and using the `debug` instead of `release` folder within `target`). If @Philx0 ran this code as demonstrated, it would likely be significantly faster in release mode.

Comment: If your CPU supports SIMD, you can use the [simd-json](https://crates.io/crates/simd-json) crate, and compile with `RUSTFLAGS="-Ctarget-cpu=native" cargo build --release`.

Comment: If compiled with `--release` the time goes down to 112 ± 7 ms

Answer (score 5):

### A rewrite of noodle man’s solution in C

````c
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024

int main(void) {
    int str = 0;
    int escape = 0; //backslash

    int depth = 0;
    int maxdepth = 0;

    char buf[BUFSIZE];

    while (fgets(buf, BUFSIZE, stdin)) {
        for (size_t i = 0; buf[i]; i++) {
            if (buf[i] == '\n') goto print;

            if (escape) {
                escape = 0;
                continue;
            }

            if (buf[i] == '\\') {
                escape = 1;
            } else if (buf[i] == '\"') {
                str = !str;
            } else if (!str) {
                if (buf[i] == '{' || buf[i] == '[') {
                    depth++;
                    if (depth > maxdepth) maxdepth = depth;
                } else if (buf[i] == '}' || buf[i] == ']') depth--;
            }
        }
    }

    print:;

    printf("%d\n", maxdepth);
}```
````

Comment: It’s times like this when I wish I knew a little C :P

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org)

I honestly have no idea how fast it is.

*EDIT: Since the challenge is no longer asking for JSON validation, using `JSON.parse()` may now seem a bit overkill. But this built-in is apparently reasonably well optimized and still faster than a simpler 100% JS parser.*

```javascript
const readline = require('readline');

// set up the readline interface
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false
});

// the following callback is invoked when a line is read
rl.on('line', str => {
  let json;

  try {
    // attempt to parse the line as JSON
    json = JSON.parse(str);
  }
  catch(e) {
    // if it fails, force the result to null
    json = null;
  }

  // recursive function computing the max. depth
  function search(node) {
    // look for anything whose typeof is 'object' but is not null
    if(typeof node == 'object' && node !== null) {
      // for an array, use the node itself
      // for a genuine object, use the list of its values
      let list = Array.isArray(node) ? node : Object.values(node);
      // return 1 right away if the list is empty
      // otherwise, do a recursive call for each element in the list
      // and return the highest result + 1
      return list.length ? 1 + Math.max(...list.map(search)) : 1;
    }
    // return 0 for non-iterable elements
    return 0;
  }

  // initial call to search
  console.log(search(json));

  // we're supposed to process only one line, so force exit
  process.exit();
});
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZExb8IwEIX3/IorA3FUapUVlFYdW6ll6IgYjLmAkbFT@4JAiN9OLzZUbYck1nfvvbuct2qvog6mpQfnV3i5aO8iQUC1ssYh1Hz86kxAUd5YWU2L4iqzSZC51HwifHWEoVEaxakAMK7taAJt8BpjlJFWxo2Y@47@Fxj1FXbvjFN2Ao2yEYtz3y5Y6Z0oU/sRRApQP0Gfb5FgG71jDVvDMUFIiEd7@5x9yFaFiII9HARw5kcr0huB1V@x66zNCn41ndNkmEdUgcX9cm560wg6tugb6CnUNZR@uUVNJQyHmd3VOe9myYNawzur4SUEdZQmpu81@Tn7JjBLSXKvbIcxF6fXiIDUBZdSpEW3pg3bxnAP74o2cqcOQkqZqjvVijx4VXHmOCeci18pjz@/2l@ltyitX19Not9Ilfre7gcPhgQTvo3LZX4aqMEE5ovzCOYDtdSDxeIb)

Comment: Won't `readFileSync(0)` wait for EOF, not a newline? (Also, not that this matters because it's tested on Linux, but that always throws EISDIR on Windows.)

Comment: Result: 276 ± 18 ms on this file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/json-iterator/test-data/master/large-file.json (note: I first had to remove all the new lines from the file)

Comment: The challenge has been edited so that you don't need to handle invalid JSON. Hopefully that should speed up your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 621 bytes

```javascript
require("readline").createInterface({ input: process.stdin, output: process.stdout, terminal: false }).on("line", file => {
  let inString = false;
  let prevBackslash = false;
  let depth = 0;
  let maxDepth = 0;
  for (const char of file) {
    if (prevBackslash) {
      prevBackslash = false;
      continue;
    }
    if (char === "\\") prevBackslash = true;
    if (char === '"' && !prevBackslash) inString = !inString
    if (inString) continue;

    if ("{[".includes(char)) {
      if (++depth > maxDepth) maxDepth++;
    }
    if ("]}".includes(char)) depth--;
  }
  console.log(maxDepth);
  process.exit();
});
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVJLTsMwEJVYcorpLNpESSM-QkKp0gViw5pl24VJxq2FawfHQZWinIRNF3AO7sFpyKcJbSq8Gr95897MaD4-lU5ov__KLZ_e_1xsDb3lwpCDhlgihSJ0g7iKLT0pS4azmJwChEpzG0JqdExZFmQ2EcoHndshXEE-VHVboZgMgTOZEZRuoJWDjboPXEiCaA7FJYAkW2k_WyPUGqKWPjvgqaH3Bxa_ZpJlm2EyodTW4FUHbNnu8Rjj2oATa5VZiDfMgOaNsdvYAggOzolBl4D_fetXKVqh8sO_7LUajyiKAJdLdM80rOlKTsgTnMB4DKNBJ0cbGXVxX9wB7lEvfRKLBQZCxTJPKGt83L_BaoLntZub9wtz-8jzhlPhqjyXawSm05pbM-sda0mB1Gun16yT3VXQTlinQkp31l7d4fj23wUyDJG9xEtMiKO_uL659QtcIoZ35apsab8)

This should be faster since it doesn't check if the JSON is valid, which is no longer required. If checking the JSON was valid was required, a solution like this manually verifying validity while checking the depth might still be faster, but I don't feel like writing a JSON parser.

All this does is loop over each character of the input, ignoring strings, incrementing a depth counter whenever it encounters a `{` or `[`, decrementing the counter when it encounters a `}` or `]`, and keeping track of the maximum depth.

Comment: Hmm. Unfortunately this returns the wrong result with this data https://raw.githubusercontent.com/json-iterator/test-data/master/large-file.json. The correct result is 7 and your program returns 88.

Comment: after debugging your code, I found the cause of the error. There are two mistakes in the code, both in the backslash handling. First of all you don’t look for backslashes when in a string but backslashes only appear in strings so you are missing every single backslash. Second, you shouldn’t flip the backslash flag every time you encounter a backslash, instead you should set it to true when a backslash is encountered and then in the beginning of the loop check for the flag and skip the iteration if it is true.

Comment: @Philx0 Sorry! Thanks for your help--it is now fixed, and I have verified that it produces the correct output for the file you provided. Could you re-time the submission when you get the chance?

Comment: The result is 567 ± 143 ms which is surprisingly slower than using the built in node.js JSON module. I guess the JSON parser in node.js is heavily optimized.

Comment: @Philx0 Well it does make sense that the parser would be fast, since it’s basically just `eval`. But it is a bit surprising that going through the structure twice is faster than just once.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org)

```javascript
const isArray = Array.isArray, objectValues = Object.values, max = Math.max;
require("readline").createInterface({ input: process.stdin, output: process.stdout, terminal: false }).on("line", str => {
  const depth = JSON.parse(str, (key, value) => {
    if (value === null || typeof value !== 'object') return 0;
    const arr = isArray(value) ? value : objectValues(value);
    const depth = -~max(...arr);
    return depth;
  });
  console.log(depth);
  process.exit();
});
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVCxbsIwEN35iqsXHClYnYPSqmMrtQyVuiAG41yKqbFT20EgoL@eHk4itUz2vXvv3t3byr0MyusmzqyrsOuUsyGCDk/eyyOUkF4x1Dm49RZV/JCmxUDdRSrFPtU57OSBwFcZN4K@84nH71Z75MyjrIy2yDKh6B/x2Ub0tVTIT6Bt08YCGu8UhiBCrLQlpzbewgTlQLqdttIUUEsTEC6ZcJazND2HED2UD3CaAPSXVNjEDS318r54E430ATlxcuBfSOekxbNRAaBr4AmDsizBtsbA@Qzx2KCrezLcUWPaxzDNwGNsvYX7eZL3ltLTDmOEfLB4HOTFvwiH7l/1uPDshyLkQggaNxAGs8S4IpeEX2XOoDDuk6dWQsfY8KAjJ4S4Xbc8MckKWK4uOSyZXCu2Wv0C)

The readline part is based on other answers.

Just in case if you are interesting, it can be golfed into 70 bytes, however, this question is not tagged as code-golf.

```javascript
s=>JSON.parse(s,(_,v)=>Object(v)===v&&-~Math.max(...Object.values(v)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9BawIxEIXv/oohB0kg5gfsskKPFVoPhV5EypgdayQm2yS7WMT@9e2w6qE95b2X5M03Rxww2@S6sgixpXG0MeQCLj@lhN/QwHSau9cQd0ey5R19T5lv15M1w@Q1nPDM4QuWg2FZzxJ99S6RFImw9S6QUMayLvQcCqU9WpIXcKHrSwVdipZyNrm0LvCkvvyPOdLA/04uoK9gjz4TXJWJQYqpXQNDLeEyA7jt0VJXDoy0elu/mg5TJpm1/NCDapY3dsmyaYb5fPHz4JbGmD@L8Rul7p3Rk/HxU07Nqub0AUhnVyQnV1WP4@YiUFSw2V41bATurNhufwE)

Comment: Is assigning those static methods to variables a style-choice or does it somehow improve performance?

Comment: @noodleman I have no idea actually. But since it saves dictionary lookup in the loop, i believe it could boost performance somehow. However, it could be quite slightly. A reason doing so could be avoid the global values been overwritten by others if you are writing some JavaScript library. But I would not do so in general.

Comment: I think if you're gonna worry about things like that, you should probably move the `reduce` callback out of the loop so you don't have to recreate the function each time.

Comment: @noodleman Maybe... I had changed the reduce into `Math.max` which seems faster on my computer.

Comment: I don't see how that's calculating the depth correctly.

Comment: @Neil But, you know, it passes the testcases. Just `JSON.parse` have a second parameter which may transform the parsed object on the fly.

Comment: Result: 370 ± 16 ms

Comment: @tsh Ah, you're getting `JSON.parse` to recurse for you? That's sneaky!

Comment: @Neil Basically yes, but it seems slower than walk on it after parsed out the full tree as what Arnauld did. I have no idea why though.

Comment: _Maybe_ the reason it's slower is that the callback function never gets a chance to be JIT compiled when it's called from the built-in. Or _maybe_ the numerous calls from the built-in add a significant enough workload for the engine.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 35 bytes

```
"(\\?.)*?"

T`[]`{}
[^{}]

+`}{

..
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYpBCsIwEEX3/xTDgFB1KCTRjZsuvYC76UjSUlAoCuIu5OwxKLj7773/Wt73R6qb7hwrd@M49NvdwMAlqsVcoNdcDNjHkoG@r1UN6oS8UBA6CB0bk5LzwYSI1BpnTnxqswgpp2nmJn8ueFfwz@Dbsq5PxvelNs2J7QM) Link includes test suite. Probably not going to win any awards for speed. Explanation:

```
"(\\?.)*?"
```

Delete all string literals.

```
T`[]`{}
```

Change square brackets into braces.

```
[^{}]
```

Delete everything other than braces.

```
+`}{
```

Merge adjacent containers at the same depth.

```
..
```

Count the maximum depth.

Answer (score 1):

## [GNU AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), ~11ms

```
BEGIN {
	FPAT = "(\"([^\"])*\")+|."
	m = 0
}

{
	printf "%s -> ", $0
	gsub(/'\\'\"[^'\\\"']*'\\'\"/, "", $0)
	gsub(/\\"/, "\"\"", $0)
	for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
		if ($i == "[" || $i == "{") {
			a++
			m = (a > m ? a : m)
		} else if ($i == "]" || $i == "}") {
			a--
		}
	}
	print m
	m = 0
}

Result:
123 -> 0
[] -> 1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -> 1
[ [ 123],   []] -> 2
[{"a": []}, ["abc"]] -> 3
{"a": 321} -> 1
{"a": []} -> 2
"hello" -> 0
["abc[]bca"] -> 1
["\",[],\""] -> 1
["",[],""] -> 2
["\"",[],""] -> 2
["\"",[],"\""] -> 2
"[\\" -> 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVBNT8JAED13fsXLBENLF6GgFxSMJmK8EA/edpdkIVQbqRiq8VD62@u0hYaD2U1m3sfOzoz7/SjLh8en5wVy8uYv96@Ygn3Dvl4atkHPcBAeLpm8VIQhFUTi@9onn98x@CJDfwZW6AzJe8t@Vv6ga0zXsF5KNNy1vQYPFLi2BSefaUgj5yTEuz38RL6JbpDgdorFXJIwDKrWvCSG3xFV2tOMwwFHkHOjey4Mq1D16TvMkOIODhOkUtorsNlmG5wVsedFirZIv1@5qbr1lEjb0csyGo1JW9KRwkhhrHClcC0YGiJZBUBbwTk7nkhaKGh2qzUL2XDjUVRQKxO/b7bbHVPt0na1dizPZSdKWyWbqUCd85H/B9Q21rJQ@gM)

Comment: `["\\","["]` → 2 should be 1.

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), 715 bytes

```go
package main

import (
	"bufio"
	"fmt"
	"os"
)

func calcDepth(data string) int {
	depth, maxDepth := 0, 0
	inString := false
	escaped := false
	for _, r := range data {
		switch r {
		case '\\':
			escaped = !escaped
		case '"':
			if !escaped {
				inString = !inString
			}
			escaped = false
		case '{', '[':
			if !inString {
				depth++
				if depth > maxDepth {
					maxDepth = depth
				}
			}
			escaped = false
		case '}', ']':
			if !inString && depth > 0 {
				depth--
			}
			escaped = false
		default:
			escaped = false
		}
	}
	return maxDepth
}

func main() {
	var data string

	scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

	if scanner.Scan() {
		data = scanner.Text()
	}

	fmt.Println(calcDepth(data))
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVLRaoMwFH1OvuIuD1WplT4L7mnPY9C9WRmpJm2YRolxLRS/3SXRpS2MDQRz7zn3nBO9x3aaOlp@0iODhgqJsWi6VmkIMSKHgYuWmANvtH21PcERxnyQJZS0Ll9Yp09hRTWFXishjxEIqeGKUWWR2CheHAfSDLYxbDEScueYtsNp3TOMWF/SjlV3Hd4q@IhB2Zai0kRzHkYX9Wehy5OBbFHSnkGw3wepKbxOBk/L0VPIzBDcQ24e3eKYoZ@zBcZHwSXXonYNYgjym6QXmTXd3dfrWZ@DK@H59i1mFvJ1NlNcd/zXfLTmxS/mq5W32t4n2Wz@0KwYp0Ot099RM2QexfSgpM@Px2UD7LqEkbX6ogrutgBjZKSkZO4HuiVKXtl5N/fCtk92uhLSbJK9wUJNLDzLIaeVeeSdXXQY2SxmNRqdvBkTXcvwcQWjyCSbpvxKKEkhL8YYckIPJSmKbw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org)

```rkt
#lang typed/racket/base

(require typed/json)

#|

Calculate the maximum depth of a JSON object read from input

Algorithm:

1. Read user input and parse JSON.
2. If input has no data, return 0.
2. Begin `max-depth` with the parsed JSON data and depth of 0.
   a. If the JSON input is a list, loop over each element of the list and pass
      the element as an input for `max-depth` and increment the depth. Repeat step 2.
   b. If the JSON input is a hash table, use each values of the table as the input list
      for step 2.a.
   c. If the JSON input is a number, string, boolean, or null, return the depth.
3. Print the maximum depth.

|#

(: max-depth (-> JSExpr Real Real))
(define (max-depth input depth)
  (let ([depth+1 (+ depth 1)])
    (cond [(list? input)
           (apply max
                  (cons depth+1
                        (map (λ ([elem : JSExpr]) : Real
                               (max-depth elem depth+1))
                             input)))]
          [(hash? input)
           (apply max
                  (cons depth+1
                        (hash-map input
                                  (λ ([_ : Symbol] [value : JSExpr]) : Real
                                    (max-depth value depth+1)))))]
          [else depth])))

(: main (-> (U JSExpr EOF) Real))
(define (main input)
  (cond [(equal? eof input) 0]
        [else (max-depth input 0)]))

(displayln (main (read-json)))

#| Tests [Remove line to run after input, if all pass, nothing will display.]

(require (only-in typed/rackunit check-equal?))
(check-equal? (main (string->jsexpr "[]")) 1)
(check-equal? (main (string->jsexpr "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]")) 1)
(check-equal? (main (string->jsexpr "[ [ 123],   []]")) 2)
(check-equal? (main (string->jsexpr "[{\"a\": []}, [\"abc\"]]")) 3)
(check-equal? (main (string->jsexpr "{\"a\": 321}")) 1)
(check-equal? (main (string->jsexpr "{\"a\": []}")) 2)
(check-equal? (main (string->jsexpr "\"hello\"")) 0)
(check-equal? (main (string->jsexpr "[\"abc[]bca\"]")) 1)

Tests [Remove line to run after input, if all pass, nothing will display.] |#
```

### Compilation

Once Racket is installed one your system, simply run:

```
raco exe /path/to/this_file.rkt
```

Best compiled without the tests.

### Explanation

Racket provides a nice built-in package called [`json`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/json/index.html) that parses JSON expressions (`JSExpr`). All lists in the JSON expression are parsed into [Racket Lists](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/pairs.html) and all dictionaries are parsed into [Hash Tables](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/hash-tables.html) where the keys are [Symbols](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/symbols.html) and the values are other `JSExpr`s. The reason I am using Typed Racket is that it is [potentially faster](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/Optimization_in_Typed_Racket.html) than the dynamically typed language.

### Conclusion

This is my submission for the challenge, I am not that great at optimizing code, so I don't expect peak performance in its runs. I did do a sample test on my machine with a 64kB minified JSON file which ran (according to `time`) at about 700ms. As a note though, my CPU is Intel 2 Duo E8500 and 2GB RAM, so I think it should be faster on other machines :)

Have an amazing weekend!